# Combobox not filling from database C#

Tags: c#, combobox

I'm trying to fill a combo box on from load from a database, I'm getting the error "Invalid object name 'POOL'"

Form load event to populate dropdown on form load

```
private void FRMAddTeam_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CMBBXPool.Items.Count > 0)
            CMBBXPool.Items.Clear();

        Database.CLSDB DatabaseClass = new Database.CLSDB();
        DatabaseClass.FillDropDownList();

    }
```

This is the code in my database connection class

```
    public void FillDropDownList()
    {
        string PoolName = "";
        Team.FRMAddTeam TeamAdd = new Team.FRMAddTeam();
        SqlConnection conn = GetConnection();
        string selStmt = "SELECT [Name] FROM dbo.TBL_pool";
        SqlCommand selCmd = new SqlCommand(selStmt, conn);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = selCmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                PoolName = reader["Name"].ToString();


                TeamAdd.addPoolItem(PoolName);
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex) { throw ex; }
        finally { conn.Close(); }
        return;
    }
```

Code to add the pool name

```
    public void addPoolItem(string PoolName)
    {
        CMBBXPool.Items.Add(PoolName);

    }
```

[image]

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Does your database have a table called `POOL`?

Comment: On which line do you get this error?

Comment: @RowlandShaw Yes I do have a table called POOL

Comment: @PraveenPaulose it is an exception when it runs, shows up in the output as additional info

Comment: @AndrewBruce Where? You don't have a table named `Pool`; you have `TBL_Pool`.

Comment: Since the code in the question does not refer to anything named POOL as such, the code that crashes is not in the question. You need to debug your application and figure out where it throws that exception and then, if necessary, post that code. By "necessary" I mean that you still need help figuring it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs to be:

```
public void FillDropDownList(Team.FRMAddTeam TeamAdd)
    {
        string PoolName = "";
        SqlConnection conn = GetConnection();
        string selStmt = "SELECT [Name] FROM dbo.TBL_pool";
        SqlCommand selCmd = new SqlCommand(selStmt, conn);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = selCmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                PoolName = reader["Name"].ToString();
                TeamAdd.addPoolItem(PoolName);
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex) { throw ex; }
        finally { conn.Close(); }
        return;
    }
```

You call it from your form like this:

```
DatabaseClass.FillDropDownList(this);
```

This will work, however it is strongly advised to change the implementation of your database class and remove tight coupling with GUI.

**It is WRONG to fill your GUI from database class - instead of that, you should return data from your database class and bind your data to GUI in the GUI class.**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_orgy

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns

Comment: It needs the "TeamAdd" to reference correctly otherwise "addPoolItem" method cannot be found

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you dont have table `Pool`.Are you sure its there?

Log into your SQL management studio  and use query analyzer to run the same command.

There could be many reasons for that If your schema is different or do you have permission to access that table ? or are you checking the right database ?

**UPDATE:**

You should try using `SELECT [Name] FROM dbo.TBL_Pool`

Comment: Well, an answer with so many questions asked looks like a comment.

Comment: There is a Table, I've just included a picture of the dtabase, databse has no passowrd to access etc. and yes it is the right database, only have 1

Comment: @AndrewBruce Yes there is a table; but there is no table named `Pool`. It is named as `TBL_Pool`

Comment: Ok so fixed that, it now runs with no errors at all however does not enter any of the values into the dropdown

Comment: You are always starting from 0. Move this `Team.FRMAddTeam TeamAdd = new Team.FRMAddTeam();` out of the reader loop!